# Selenium WebDriver. After waiting for the element click() freezes test

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need to click on the dynamically generated element using Selenium WebDriver (Java API).
I'm waiting for this element to appear with WebDriverWait and then clicking on it. This click succeeds but the following click on the different static element freezes the whole test. Here is the code:

```
webDriver.get(alfrescoURL + "/share/page/create-document");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);

WebElement documentTypeList = webDriver.findElement(By.id("template_x002e_create-document_x002e_create-document_x0023_default_documenttype-selected-form-button-button"));
documentTypeList.click();
WebElement listItem = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yui-gen100")));
listItem.click();
// Choosing to create in new project
WebElement projectLink = webDriver.findElement(By.id("template_x002e_create-document_x002e_create-document_x0023_default_projecttype-entry1"));
projectLink.click();
```

`documentTypeList.click()` opens a drop-down list, `listItem.click()` chooses an item, `projectLink.click()` makes a choice in the group of radiobuttons. Test silently freezes on `projectLink.click()`. It looks like this `click()` infinitly waits for page reloading that happens by some reason while it shouldn't. (Disappearing of the list after choosing an item is made by javascript that doesn't make any AJAX requests.)

I think there is something about `click()` blocking i don't understand. It says in it's javadoc that it attempts to block only if it causes a page to load. Nevertheless here i get a block for some reason.

If i insert a thread sleep before `projectLink.click()` then test works fine. It agrees with a hypothesis that i get a infinite block on `click()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before where the test runs faster than the drop down can contract and can't click the following element. Instead of using arbitrary sleeps (although in rare cases they are necessary), can you put in a wait for a class change in the drop down?

For example, if I want to wait for the drop down to contract before moving on, I'll wait for the class of the select to change from "active" to "closed". This, of course, assumes your HTML has these dynamic classes in place.

Another possibility is to set an implicit wait, giving yourself enough padding for instances like these:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try other click options too:

- a) `Actions#click()`
- b) Javascript click()

If any of those click works then it means the issue is with the selenium's WebElement Click method which needs to be reported.